# Protobuff message from go client to python server

Tags: python, go, protocol-buffers

I want to send a message from go client to python server.
I am using protobuff for the same.

**Go side message structure**

```
type CreateProductInfo struct  {
  name string
  fruits []*Fruits
}

type Fruits struct  {
 name string
}
```

I am expecting the below response in my python server.

```
{
   name : "product_info"
   fruits : [
              {
                name : "Apple"
              }
            ]
 }
```

Instead, I'm getting this.

```
 {
   name : "product_info"
   fruits : [

                name : "Apple"

            ]
 }
```

Comment: Please show us your proto file

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, there is no problem with rpc message transfer. Instead, you are receiving the wrong message type. 
Please make sure you are preparing the protobuf message in the correct format.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type CreateProductInfo struct {
    Name   string    `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=name" json:"name,omitempty"`
    Fruits []*Fruits `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=fruits" json:"fruits,omitempty"`
}

type Fruits struct {
    Name string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=name" json:"name,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    productInfo := &CreateProductInfo{
        Name: "product_info",
        Fruits: []*Fruits{
            &Fruits{
                Name: "apple",
            },
            &Fruits{
                Name: "orange",
            },
            &Fruits{
                Name: "mango",
            },
        },
    }

    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(&productInfo, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    os.Stdout.Write(b)
}
```

This returns like this.

```
{
    "name": "product_info",
    "fruits": [
        {
            "name": "apple"
        },
        {
            "name": "orange"
        },
        {
            "name": "mango"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Go-Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/Kd66eJa1e8r)